# Python: raise an exception when out of main memory

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I am handling large arrays with Python and the library numpy. Sometimes I create unexpectedly huge arrays, which fills totally the main memory (RAM) of the computer, and starts writing on the slow second memory (swap, hard disk). When this happens, I cannot do anything but wait for the end of the writing (which can take dozens of minutes) or perform a force shutdown. To avoid this situation, I would prefer to raise an exception when the array I am trying to allocate is too large for the RAM. How to do this?

OS: Windows 7 64 bits

Edit: I don't agree with the duplicate tag: I'm not asking about how to get the available memory, I'm asking about built-ins mechanisms that prevent me to allocate objects in memory without paging.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html?highlight=setrlimit

Answer (score 1):

You could use [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#memory) and periodically check `psutil.virtual_memory()` or similar.